# Better ways to replace text - performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Are there better more performant ways to replace text then using the regex code below, specially if text is large and constantly accessed by different users. I understand performance gains may be negligible, but i'm wondering if there are better way to do it. This is what i use to replace foo with foonew

```
str.replace(/foo/gi, 'foonew')
```

Update: Text data gets retrieved from database into a textarea holder before doing word replacement.  I then access textarea value, replace the words, then append updated text to body

Comment: *"...specially if the DOM is large..."* Are you doing a `.replace()` to modify the DOM? Something like `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(...`

Comment: how does the access load impact you? if it's really really relevant, can't you just send the data perfected?

Comment: @patrick, i have data being retrieved from the database, before outputing to screen, I need to replace certain words. This is security related.

Comment: @leon you are missing the question.

Comment: Replacing text client-side isn't really going to help with security. Couldn't they just view source?

Comment: @ick, your response is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Pinkie: I'm sure that's why @icktoofay posted it as a comment. Sometimes people here are asking the wrong question and aren't aware of it (not saying you).

Comment: @patrick i agree. I don't feel like explaining to ick how XSS security works. It's not what the question is about

Comment: @patrick, i forgot to mention, the data is being retrieved and put in a temporary textarea before i do the text replacement. So i access the textarea value, replace the words, then append to body

Comment: @Pinkie: So you're looking for `<script>` tags? (I'm no XSS expert myself.)

Comment: @patrick, it's more then script tags, sometimes users inject javascript inside inline styling in the form of expression, alert, javascript.... I replace the words before data goes to database, then replace words back after i retrieve them from database. I use hidden textarea as a temporary text holder

Comment: @Pinkie: Sorry, I don't have a good answer with respect to performance. More info in the question may help people give you a better answer.  ;o)

Comment: @patrick i understand. Maybe the question was not very clear. It's basically asking for better way to replace text in DOM. database has nothing to do with this since text is retrieved to DOM before replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Well, patric dw's comment is probably the right answer here.  But let's suppose for the sake of argument that you really had to replace a random substring in some larger string, and there was no simple trick to avoid it.  Here are three possibilities:

1. If you are replacing a string with one of smaller length, then you can just shift the characters to the right over it to make up the difference.  This avoids reallocating the string.
2. If the replacement is the same size, you can just do it in place with no copying.
3. Finally, if it is larger, you can do the string replacement lazily.   Just store an object with the string you are substituting and the start/end of the segment that was replaced.  This way you can avoid copying.  Of course this is much more complicated than just doing the string replacement by hand, so I would probably avoid it unless the performance considerations were really dire.

Answer (score 0):

> Text data gets retrieved from database into a textarea holder before doing word replacement. I then access textarea value, replace the words, then append updated text to body.

The most effiecient (and most secure) way to do this is to replace the words, server-side, before ever sending the data.

Then your JS (which the user can modify!) has to do nothing but display the information.

Depending on traffic/volume, it may pay to even have sanitized versions of the text, stored in the database.